# How to easily get rid of all of the unused locales?

Tags: locale

It annoys me to have locales on my system that I will never use. Its wasted space and inefficient. Is there a way I can get rid of them permanently and have it only in USA English and Metric option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted mine using [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux) which was quick and easy. Detail at https://bleachbit.blogspot.com/2009/07/free-disk-space-localepurge.html.

1. Install BleachBit.
2. Start BleachBit
3. Go to the preferences and check languages you want to keep.
4. Close the preferences, and check the checkbox for Localizations.
5. Click delete.
6. As you install new software packages, run BleachBit again

Answer (score 0):

This [trashes](https://man.archlinux.org/man/trash.1.en) all directories that are not named `en_US` in the directory `/usr/share/locales`:

```
find /usr/share/locale/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -a ! '(' -name 'en_US' ')' -exec sudo trash {} +
```